# Set layer different style to multiple layer at once in model designer

Tags: qgis, style, algorithm, model

I made a model that generates multiple layers

Among other entries, a style file is required as input that I use to set one of the output layer.

I would like to use a folder input and to set multiple style to multiple layers with a minimum input field required.

Ideally, I would prefer to set everything in the model, but as far as I know, it's not possible to set layer without a style file.

There is also the “Style Database” (XML) that I can create with the processing tool, but I don't understand how to use the file after that.

[image: Presentation of input]

[image: style file entry settings]

I would like to choose “folder” and then in “Set Layer Style” choose something like “Style.file1”

Is there any way to do that, or something similar?

I'm trying to produce a model as simple as possible to use